# can't parse json file in groovy and jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

ı can't get name of images. ı need sha256's value to compare images. ı want to compare backup's sha256 with latest'sha256

jenkins and openshift dsl

**json:**

```
{
    "apiVersion": "image.openshift.io/v1",
    "kind": "ImageStream",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-03-09T07:16:09Z",
        "generation": 15,
        "labels": {
            "app": "account"
        },
        "name": "account",
        "namespace": "tosla-int",
        "resourceVersion": "37110906",
        "selfLink": "/apis/image.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/tosla-int/imagestreams/account",
        "uid": "362935bc-423b-11e9-9f1b-005056a04991"
    },
    "spec": {
        "lookupPolicy": {
            "local": false
        },
        "tags": [
            {
                "annotations": null,
                "from": {
                    "kind": "ImageStreamImage",
                    "name": "account@sha256:99b8efe4b68d79070bfbf7c5209eb959c141e53f0325938985dd30ab0eca0430"
                },
                "generation": 13,
                "importPolicy": {},
                "name": "backup",
                "referencePolicy": {
                    "type": "Source"
                }
            },
            {
                "annotations": null,
                "from": {
                    "kind": "ImageStreamImage",
                    "name": "account@sha256:a0ada237e1db2d986d844217fa4dda326f577647a73cae525f6a0554ff30b74f",
                    "namespace": "tosla-dev"
                },
                "generation": 14,
                "importPolicy": {},
                "name": "latest",
                "referencePolicy": {
                    "type": "Source"
                }
            },
            {
                "annotations": null,
                "from": {
                    "kind": "ImageStreamImage",
                    "name": "account@sha256:a0ada237e1db2d986d844217fa4dda326f577647a73cae525f6a0554ff30b74f"
                },
                "generation": 15,
                "importPolicy": {},
                "name": "uc",
                "referencePolicy": {
                    "type": "Source"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": {
        "dockerImageRepository": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account",
        "tags": [
            {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "created": "2019-04-10T09:52:02Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:99b8efe4b68d79070bfbf7c5209eb959c141e53f0325938985dd30ab0eca0430",
                        "generation": 13,
                        "image": "sha256:99b8efe4b68d79070bfbf7c5209eb959c141e53f0325938985dd30ab0eca0430"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-04-09T19:48:48Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:2066a813b65b7235b358bd5abb5467d4b5cf8d8155c4c8746bb21ea8f9f255f5",
                        "generation": 11,
                        "image": "sha256:2066a813b65b7235b358bd5abb5467d4b5cf8d8155c4c8746bb21ea8f9f255f5"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-04-04T12:57:36Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:c0ac0f834c84f3d3f8efd33600563ec69595eca5297482b8d292341d80b31bff",
                        "generation": 9,
                        "image": "sha256:c0ac0f834c84f3d3f8efd33600563ec69595eca5297482b8d292341d80b31bff"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-03-28T17:05:44Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:77d5925c828556072533f813ff105cfc8edd73c5eebbacbc3108173fc70186d4",
                        "generation": 7,
                        "image": "sha256:77d5925c828556072533f813ff105cfc8edd73c5eebbacbc3108173fc70186d4"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-03-27T20:15:57Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:e55065998aeabe5695c918dddbaefcb3b1df2dd00c25381287d593d040596a19",
                        "generation": 5,
                        "image": "sha256:e55065998aeabe5695c918dddbaefcb3b1df2dd00c25381287d593d040596a19"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-03-10T08:13:15Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:22ae5678b5b0a17bb3fe7c8c23e5c3d857dfdcbec36d922bb580bff44fde3c06",
                        "generation": 3,
                        "image": "sha256:22ae5678b5b0a17bb3fe7c8c23e5c3d857dfdcbec36d922bb580bff44fde3c06"
                    }
                ],
                "tag": "backup"
            },
            {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "created": "2019-04-17T16:49:39Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:a0ada237e1db2d986d844217fa4dda326f577647a73cae525f6a0554ff30b74f",
                        "generation": 14,
                        "image": "sha256:a0ada237e1db2d986d844217fa4dda326f577647a73cae525f6a0554ff30b74f"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-04-09T19:49:21Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:99b8efe4b68d79070bfbf7c5209eb959c141e53f0325938985dd30ab0eca0430",
                        "generation": 12,
                        "image": "sha256:99b8efe4b68d79070bfbf7c5209eb959c141e53f0325938985dd30ab0eca0430"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-04-04T12:58:16Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:2066a813b65b7235b358bd5abb5467d4b5cf8d8155c4c8746bb21ea8f9f255f5",
                        "generation": 10,
                        "image": "sha256:2066a813b65b7235b358bd5abb5467d4b5cf8d8155c4c8746bb21ea8f9f255f5"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-03-28T17:06:17Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:c0ac0f834c84f3d3f8efd33600563ec69595eca5297482b8d292341d80b31bff",
                        "generation": 8,
                        "image": "sha256:c0ac0f834c84f3d3f8efd33600563ec69595eca5297482b8d292341d80b31bff"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-03-27T20:16:37Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:77d5925c828556072533f813ff105cfc8edd73c5eebbacbc3108173fc70186d4",
                        "generation": 6,
                        "image": "sha256:77d5925c828556072533f813ff105cfc8edd73c5eebbacbc3108173fc70186d4"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-03-25T18:15:14Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:e55065998aeabe5695c918dddbaefcb3b1df2dd00c25381287d593d040596a19",
                        "generation": 4,
                        "image": "sha256:e55065998aeabe5695c918dddbaefcb3b1df2dd00c25381287d593d040596a19"
                    },
                    {
                        "created": "2019-03-09T07:22:20Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:22ae5678b5b0a17bb3fe7c8c23e5c3d857dfdcbec36d922bb580bff44fde3c06",
                        "generation": 2,
                        "image": "sha256:22ae5678b5b0a17bb3fe7c8c23e5c3d857dfdcbec36d922bb580bff44fde3c06"
                    }
                ],
                "tag": "latest"
            },
            {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "created": "2019-04-17T17:56:02Z",
                        "dockerImageReference": "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/tosla-int/account@sha256:a0ada237e1db2d986d844217fa4dda326f577647a73cae525f6a0554ff30b74f",
                        "generation": 15,
                        "image": "sha256:a0ada237e1db2d986d844217fa4dda326f577647a73cae525f6a0554ff30b74f"
                    }
                ],
                "tag": "uc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**code :**

```
def image_list = sh(script:  '  oc get is/account -o json  ', returnStdout: true).trim() as String
println image_list
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(image_list)
String idValue = parsedJson.apiVersion
print idValue     ?????
```

how can i print value of latest image and value of backup image. ı want to compare 256 images digitest

Comment: [`readJSON`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) to the rescue. I put the JSON in a variable and ran `def imageList = readJSON text: jsonString` and it seems you have a misformed JSON: run it and you'll get `Expected a ',' or '}' at character 1222`

Comment: `println parsedJson.spec.tags[-1]` prints the last tag

Comment: ı have updated json file

Answer (score 0):

You can print them like this:

```
parsedJson.spec.tags.each { tag -> 
    if (tag.name == "latest" || tag.name == "backup") {
        println tag.from.name
    }
}
```